# RecyclerView scrolls to end after smoothScrollToPosition(0)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager` (`Vertical`, not inverted). When I insert or move item to 0 position, such method is invoked:

```
private void scrollToStart() {
        int firstVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recentList.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        boolean notScrolling = recentList.getScrollState() == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
        if (firstVisiblePosition < 2 && notScrolling) {
            recentList.scrollToPosition(0);
        }
}
```

But sometimes it smooth scrolls to the end of list.

(I've seen such behaviour in some apps like Instagram. It looks like list scrolls to top and then starts to move in the opposite direction.)

If I replace `smoothScrollToPosition` with simple `scrollToPosition`, it behaves as it should.

How to prevent this scroll?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the fact items are recyclable was the cause to it. Try to place `this.setIsRecyclable(false);` inside of your ViewHolder

Comment: but this will slow down RecyclerView